# SQL Server Stored Procedure Using a Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, wildcard

I have a linked server that connects to our ERP data.  If I run the following query I get the results I want.

```
SELECT ItemCode, ItemType, ItemCodeDesc FROM OPENQUERY(MAS90_Link_LPS, 'SELECT * FROM CI_Item') WHERE (ItemCode LIKE '%3M%')
```

I then created a stored procedure that should allow me to change the search string.  The problem is it returns an empty record set.

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[FindItems] @Itemcode char(30)
as
Select @itemcode = '%'+rtrim(@itemcode)+'%';
SELECT ItemCode, ItemType, ItemCodeDesc
FROM OPENQUERY(MAS90_Link_LPS, 'SELECT * FROM CI_Item') WHERE (ItemCode LIKE @itemcode);
return;
GO
exec FindItems @itemcode='3M'
```

I don't understand why the same query returns nothing in a stored procedure but gives the proper results when I execute the query in a normal window.  In testing I've found that I can get a result as long as I don't include the wild card symbol.  Example is if I search for an exact string it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the @Itemcode of the stored procedure to varchar rather than char. With the way you have it there are a number of spaces at the end of @itemcode that may be causing an issue.

Comment: That's why I use rtrim to remove all spaces.  I will try that though.

Comment: Its not that stupid. You can't store a trimmed string in a fixed width field and expect it not to pad the result.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks for the assist.  I thought I was taking care of that with the rtrim command in the procedure.  Apparently all it needed was a different datatype.